# Tempo de processamento e tempo de relógio

Tags: desempenho, ciência-da-computação

Qual a diferença entre o tempo de processamento e o tempo de relógio?

Comment: Como a maioria dos processadores atuais suportam várias threads então o tempo de relógio é usualmente maior que o tempo de processamento (considerando que está se referindo ao tempo de uso da CPU) já que o processador partilhará o uso entre as diversas threads e não será computado o tempo em que estiver aguardando.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O tempo de relógio, muitas vezes chamados de *wall clock time* porque é o que você pode avaliar de tempo passado para executar uma tarefa olhando para o relógio de parede, é quanto tempo demora para executar aquilo de forma observável.

Em geral as linguagens possuem bibliotecas que tem uma infraestrutura para medir isso de forma simples e confiável, algo como um `StopWatch`. Em alguns casos a medição é feita fora do executável, especialmente quando quer se medir a carga do executável também.

O que chama de tempo de processamento talvez seja tempo de processador. Essa medida indica quanto de recurso de processador foi gasto e não o tempo em si para executar. É quanto tempo foi gasto com instruções do processador. E pode ser dividido em tempo de usuário (sua aplicação mesmo) e tempo de sistema (o que sua aplicação delegou para o sistema operacional fazer para você). É mais uma medida de gasto de combustível do que quanto tempo levou para fazer uma volta, apesar de falarmos em tempo. è uma proporção de uso do recurso disponível.

É comum certas tarefas que tem IO gastar tempo de relógio sem gastar tempo de processador porque ela fica esperando algo ser executado fora do processador. Então dá diferença.

O fato de ter mais de um processador pode paralelizar o processamento, então você gasta tempo de processador no total muito mais que o tempo de relógio, porque cada processador é uma máquina diferente que te dá um total de tempo disponível para processar.

Note que criar *threads* simplesmente usadas não garante isso, precisa que a paralelização ocorra. Se criar mais *threads* que processadores disponíveis em caso extremo podem ocorrer o oposto, o tempo de relógio ser maior que o tempo de processador, mas sempre haverá perda, ainda que não inverta o tempo do relógio.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).